# ASP.NET C# Returning Unknown Integers for Unknown Reason

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, sql, ajax

WebMethod:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string[] GetLikes(int Id)
{
    List<Like> Likes = Like.GetById(Id, false);
    string[] Senders = new string[Likes.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < Likes.Count; i++)
    {
        Senders[i] = Likes[i].Sender;            
    }
    return Senders;
}
```

jQuery:

```
        $(".StreamLike").live("mouseover", function () {

            var Id = $(this).parent().parent().find(".StreamIndex").html();
            alert(Id);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'Default.aspx/GetLikes',
                data: JSON.stringify({ "Id": Id }),
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: LikesSuccess,
                error: LikesError
            });
        });
```

[issue img http://www.taaraf.com/issue.png](http://www.taaraf.com/issue.png)

Id is passed from JavaScript code as 338 correctly. Why does it show as 152? This isn't allowing me to get the proper data. 
Ideas?

Comment: .StreamIndex is a <asp:Label nested in a ListView that contains Text='<%# Eval("Id") ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Id is displayed in hexadecimal notation (as starts with 0x), 0x152 is equal to 338.

Answer (score 1):

The number is displayed as hexadecimal, you can see this by the `0x....`. Hex 152 is Dec 338.

Answer (score 1):

This is hexadecimal. It's the same number

```
0 = 0
1 = 1
2 = 2
3 = 3
4 = 4
5 = 5
6 = 6
7 = 7
8 = 8
9 = 9
A = 10
B = 11
C = 12
D = 13
E = 14
F = 15
```

Computers LOVE binary. So representing numbers in bases that of the form 2^n is awesome for working with computers ;)